# Why isn't a.out in machine language?

Tags: c, executable, machine-code

I compile the following program with `gcc` and receive an output executable file `a.out`.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
  printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

When I execute `cat a.out`, why is the file in "gibberish" (what is this called?) and not machine language of 0s and 1s:

```
??????? H__PAGEZERO(__TEXT__text__TEXT?`??__stubs__TEXT 
P__unwind_info__TEXT]P]__eh_frame__TEXT?H??__DATA__program_vars [continued]
```

Comment: `xxd -b a.out`. There, 0s and 1s. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file is in 0 and 1, but when you open it with text editor those bits are grouped in bytes and then treated as text ;) In Linux you could try to disassemble the output file to ensure that it contains machine instructions (x86 architecture):

`objdump -D -mi386 a.out`

Example output:

```
1:  83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
4:  be 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%esi
9:  bf 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%edi
```

The second column contains that 0's and 1's in hexadecimal notation and the third column contains mnemonic assembler instructions.

If you want to display those 0's and 1's simply type:

`xxd -b a.out`

Example output:

```
 0000000: 01111111 01000101 01001100 01000110 00000010 00000001  .ELF..
 0000006: 00000001 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000  ......
```

Comment: You should also mention that this is the case for every file, not just executables.

Comment: Yup, there is no such thing as analog files, so every single file consists of binary digits (bits). Machine code, text files, source files, object files, databases. All are binary files.

Answer (score 5):

It's in some kind of [executable file format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable).  On Linux, it's probably [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), on Mac OS X it's probably [Mach-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-o), and so on.  There's even an [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) format, but it's not that common anymore.

It can't just be bare machine instructions - the operating system needs some information about how to load it, what dynamic libraries to attach to it, etc.

Comment: While that's true, I think you missed the OP's main confusion. Even if it were bare machine instructions, the OP certainly wouldn't see 0s and 1s when he opens the file in a text editor (which is what he apparently expected).

Answer (score 1):

Characters are also made of 0's and 1's, and the computer has no way of knowing the difference. You asked it to show the file and it did.

In addition to the machine instructions, the binary file also contains layout and optional debug information which can be readable strings.

Answer (score 1):

The a.out is in a format the loader of the OS you are using can understand.  Those different texts you see are markers for different parts of the 0s and 1s you expect.

The `?` and ` show spots where there are binary unprintable data.

Answer (score 0):

The typical format on Linux systems these days is ELF.  The ELF file may contain machine code, which you can examine with the `objdump` utility.

```
$ gcc main.c
$ objdump -d -j .text a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:
(code omitted for brevity)
00000000004005ac :
  4005ac:       55                      push   %rbp
  4005ad:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4005b0:       bf 6c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40066c,%edi
  4005b5:       e8 d6 fe ff ff          callq  400490 
  4005ba:       5d                      pop    %rbp
  4005bb:       c3                      retq   
  4005bc:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

See? Machine code.  The `objdump` utility helpfully prints it in hexadecimal with the corresponding disassempled code on the right, and the addresses on the left.